# Data Type Selection

Tags: java, swing

Question:

1. My integer call function was working fine. However the double function not working. need help. if I type data selection 3 it should capture the double value and output "The Data Type You Entered is Correct else " You Entered incorrect Data Type\n Please try again".
2. Same this need to do for String value. if i select data type 1 then user need to input string value. other than that the program must output "You Entered incorrect Data Type\n Please try again"and if following attempt for string is correct than output "The Data Type You Entered is Correct "

Main program

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Q1DataType {

    public static int a, b, c, i;
    public static double d, e;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (c = 1; c > 0; c++) {
            String a = JOptionPane
                    .showInputDialog("Data Type Validation Program\n\n\n 1). String\n 2). Integer\n 3). Double\n 4). Quit the program");
            if ((b = Integer.parseInt(a)) == 2) {
                callInteger mon = new callInteger();
            }

            if ((d = Double.parseDouble(a)) == 3) {
                callDouble mon1 = new callDouble();
            }

            if ((i = Integer.parseInt(a)) == 4) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

integer class

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class callInteger {

    public static int u;

    public callInteger() {
        try {
            u = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane
                    .showInputDialog("Please input Integer Data Type"));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "The Data Type You Entered is Correct");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "You Entered invalid Data Type\n Please Try Again");
        }
    }
}
```

double class

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class callDouble {

    public static double t;

    public callDouble() {
        try {
            t = Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane
                    .showInputDialog("Please Enter Double Data Type"));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "The Data Type You Entered is Correct");
        } catch (Exception r) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "You Entered incorrect Data Type\n Please try again");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using Float.parseFloat instead of Double.parseDouble?

Comment: I tried double but does not working...any idea pls. same for string not sure how to declare and input.

Comment: can anyone pls try and help.

Comment: I dont know, but it works fine. It triggers correctly on `Integer` and `Double`.

Comment: could you send me your code that edited? may be i can try at my site.

Answer (score 0):

It's still the same functionality, but here. It works like your code works:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Q1DataType {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true) {
            String a = JOptionPane
                    .showInputDialog("Data Type Validation Program\n\n\n 1). String\n 2). Integer\n 3). Double\n 4). Quit the program");
            if (a.equals("1")) {
                // String
            }
            if (Integer.parseInt(a) == 2) {
                new callInteger();
            }
            if (Double.parseDouble(a) == 3) {
                new callDouble();
            }
            if (Integer.parseInt(a) == 4) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***EDIT***: Ah, I guess I understand now what you want to do. The problem is, that it will always autocast it to a double value. You could try something like that.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class callDouble {

    public static double t;

    public callDouble() {
        try {
            String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please Enter Double Data Type");
            if (s.contains(".")) {
                t = Double.parseDouble(s);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Data Type You Entered is Correct");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Entered incorrect Data Type\n Please try again");
            }
        } catch (Exception r) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Entered incorrect Data Type\n Please try again");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: HI Klemens...yes it ok. but the double value does not give any erroir message if I type integer value.